# Compact and weakly compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

In a **Banach space**,

is every compact set weakly compact set?

I guess its true just want to make sure.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The weak topology is coarser than the strong topology, therefore strong-compact subsets are weak-compact.

This is a purely topological fact: every cover by open sets from the coarser topology is a cover by open sets from the finer topology, and therefore a finite subcover exists a fortiori.